# Trigger function with delay when Sprites overlap in Phaser using P2 physics

Tags: overlap, phaser-framework

I want to trigger a function with a delay of two seconds that resets my ball to its standard position and ups the Score when it hits the goal.

My game looks like this:
[image: Game screenshot]

```
goal = game.add.sprite(35, 428, 'goal');
game.physics.p2.enable(goal, true);
goal.body.static = true;
goal.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.P2JS;
goal.body.data.shapes[0].sensor = true;

var shape = new p2.Circle();
ball = game.add.sprite( game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'ball');
game.physics.p2.enable(ball);
ball.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
ball.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
ball.body.data.gravityScale = 1;
ball.body.clearShapes();
ball.body.addCircle(shape);
```

I got it working once with the Overlap function in Arcade physics, but is there something equivalent to in P2?

Comment: Hi @Rrezon, welcome to SO. please add your relevant code and don't give a link to it. In addition, share with community what have you tried so far. Good luck

Comment: And please change 'delaz' to 'delays' in the title to make it understandable.